# How to connect to MS Active Directory using LDAP in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, active-directory, ldap

I need to connect to Microsoft Active Directory to retrieve user details about group membership.  I have the LDAP path and have done this many times in C sharp.  But now I need to understand how to do this in Xcode.

There are several questions relating to retrieval of data from AD, but i have not managed to find one explaining how to connect int the first place.  So any suggestions/code sample much appreciated thank you.

Comment: Hey am having the same issue, did you find a way to do this?